# Permission Denied trying to execute a .conf file. 

Tags: linux, asterisk

I'm using a virtual machine in Windows 7 and I have installed Linux on it and Asterisk software.

I want to configure the sip file to create sip user but when I type `./sip.conf` in Linux it replies `:permission denied`.

Please can you tell me how can I can configure the sip file using Linux in Asterisk `sip.conf` and `extensions.conf`

Answer (score 8):

Well, there's a whole bunch of things wrong with what you're trying to do.

1. You can't edit a file with ./  That's linux slang for "execute this thing in my current path".  .conf files aren't traditionally executable.
2. To edit a file, use some text editor like `gedit`, `emacs`, `vi`(`m`) or `nano`.
3. Try reading the manual pages online for asterisk, or try `man sip.conf` in  your terminal.

Comment: Yep .conf files on Linux are 99% simple text files that you edit with any Linux text editor, or copy them to windows machine, edit there and copy back.

Comment: @Gnudiff only problem can be with line endings, there.